# hex value to string of characters

Tags: php, binary, hex, substring, bin2hex

I have a hex number that I get from a bin2hex() call. I need a string representing this number in the format outlined below:

```
$tmp = bin2hex($foo)
// $tmp is 0x123efd
```

I need some code that will give me the string **"123efd"**.

Comment: would http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a prefix of hexadecimal (0x). You need to remove the prefix with

```
$tmp = substr(bin2hex($foo), 2); // $tmp is 123efd
//assume that prefix is only 2 digits and you always remove the 2 digits
```